# Extend on a typescript interface and change one value in the extended object

Tags: typescript, axios

Curious what approach I could use to implement the following simple ts interface extend. I don't want to get rid of the `data: {}` object since the data axios responds with is inside the response 'data' object.

**Supertype**

```js
export interface IAxiosResponse {
  data: {
    type: IAlertStatus;
    message: string;
    data?: any;
  };
}
```

**Subtype**

```js
export interface YTQueryResponse extends IAxiosResponse {
  data: {
    // how can I get 'type' and 'message' here without hardcoding supertypes type & message?
    data: IYoutubeResponse;
  } 
}
```

I pretty much just want to set up a pattern to replace *only* `data.data` while leaving the other properties alone (their inherited shape is fine). I've tried to implement a few different ts utilities to this end but so far I've been unsuccessful.

for instance, the following doesn't work because it's still looking for `data.type` and `data.message`.

```
export interface YTQueryResponse extends Omit<IAxiosResponse, "data.data"> {
  data: {
    data: IYoutubeResponse;
  };
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: does `IAxiosResponse` have a generic that specifies this? surely this is a super common usecase.

Comment: I think `IAxiosResponse` is a custom type that OP has created (ie one not offered by the library). It looks like OP's API always returns data in the following shape: `{ type: IAlertStatus; message: string; data?: <something> }`. Is this the case @Kevin? If it is the case, `IAxiosResponse` should be a generic, accepting a type parameter to allow the consumer to specific their own shape for `data`. I'll write an answer if this is the case.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, ahh your update beat me to it :)

Comment: @Wing Hello, yeah I made the type myself, I'm trying to establish a consistent API response shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by defining your own data interface then passing it to the generic of the builtin `AxiosResponse`, this is probably the easiest and most useful for most cases.

```
interface MyDataFormat<T = any> {
    type: IAlertStatus;
    message: string;
    data?: T;
}
export type IAxiosResponse<InnerData = any> = AxiosResponse<MyDataFormat<InnerData>>
// or export interface IAxiosResponse<InnerData = any> extends AxiosResponse<MyDataFormat<InnerData>> {}
export interface YTQueryResponse extends IAxiosResponse< IYoutubeResponse> {}
// or export type YTQueryResponse = IAxiosResponse< IYoutubeResponse>
```

Or if you do need to extract a field from a bigger type definition (instead of just redefining that type yourself) you can extract the field then write an interface to extend it, although typescript forces you to use some intermediate variable since `IAxiosResponse["data"]` can't go directly into the extend section of an interface. ([see this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31843))

```
type tmp = IAxiosResponse["data"]
interface MyAxiosData<D> extends tmp {
    data: D
}
export interface YTQueryResponse extends IAxiosResponse {
  data: MyAxiosData< IYoutubeResponse>
}
```

or doing it inline with just a type intersection (which won't complain as clearly if you are intersecting conflicting types but is less overhead for the programmer than above)

```
export interface YTQueryResponse extends IAxiosResponse {
  data: IAxiosResponse["data"] & {data: IYoutubeResponse};
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer

Comment: So far, I've implemented the last variation (and it's successfully working). However, my linter errors with `no-unsafe-member-access`  due to `data.data` being detected as `any`. Mousing over the `response.data?` shows both the original `data.data?: any & data.data: IYoutubeResponse`. From what I can tell, it seems like the linter is still referencing the original `any` variant and ignoring the `IYoutubeResponse`.

Comment: oh yeah, because it is any you might need to do `Omit<IAxiosResponse["data"], "data">` to explicitly not include that field but if you are using a relatively strict linter why are you using `any` in the first place and not `unknown`?

Comment: I was unaware there was a difference between `any` and `unknown`, guess I'll be reading up on that haha.

Comment: `any` is the "this was from JS so **don't type check** it": `any & X == any`, `any | X == any`. `unknown` is "idk what this is so **make sure I verify** what it is before I use it": `unknown & X == X`, `unknown | X == unknown`.

Comment: Going to be honest, the description you provided makes a lot more sense than the various other descriptions I read. Thank you.

Comment: are you searching the internet or looking for documentation on when and why it was added to typescript? [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10715) and the associated [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24439) will probably give you better detail than search engine and go more in depth about **why** it is useful than the documentation will.